# why os.system('cmd.exe') in pycharm does not open a new console

Tags: windows, pycharm, python-idle

In my python script, there is `os.system('cmd.exe')`.

The same script opens a new cmd console when executed with Python IDLE, but not when executed in PyCharm.

Any help on this?

Comment: A variation: if one runs IDLE from a cmd console with `python -m idlelib`, then the new cmd.exe `path..>` prompt goes to the existing console window.  Entering `exit` closes the new cmd.exe, but not the window, and `>>>` appears again in the IDLE Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Check `os.environ['PATH']` and `os.system("echo $PATH")`, they should be the same.

Comment: Considering they want to run `cmd`, I'm fairly sure that `os.system("echo $PATH")` simply results in `$PATH`.